# Validating Json Array to Scala list of specific length

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework

I represent a weeks data with a case class that has a list of days datas with other relevant parameters affecting the weeks datas:

```
case class WeeksData (
  data: List[DaysData],
  otherStuffRelatedToWeeksParameters: ...
)
case class DaysData (
  stuff: ...
)
```

I need to validate the input Json from the client so that the WeeksData data parameter has exactly 7 elements. How would you suggest I do that?

So far I have

```
val weeksDataValidator: Reads[List[DaysData]] = ???
implicit val weeksDataWrites = Json.writes[WeeksData]
implicit val weeksDataReads: Reads[WeeksData] = (
  (JsPath \ "weeksData").read[List[DaysData]](weeksDataValidator))(WeeksData.apply _)
```

I know I can write for Int:

```
val intValidator: Reads[Int] = min(0) keepAnd max(999)
```

So, **how to write a validator for an array/list so that the required length is fixed** (7 in this case)?

Or should I just modify the WeeksData class to such as

```
case class WeeksData (
  mon: DaysData,
  tue: DaysData,
  wed: DaysData,
  ...
  otherStuffRelatedToWeeksParameters: ...
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model is simplified for the sake of short example:

```
case class A(weeks: List[Int])

def listReads[T](length: Int)(implicit anyListReads: Reads[List[T]]) = Reads[List[T]] { js => 
  anyListReads.reads(js).filter(JsError(ValidationError(s"Length of the list must be $length")))(_.size == length)
}

implicit val reads: Reads[A] = ((JsPath \ "weeks").read[List[Int]](listReads[Int](2))).map(A.apply _)
```

Usage (from REPL):

```
scala> Json.parse("""{ "weeks": [1, 2] }""").validate[A]
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[A] = JsSuccess(A(List(1, 2)),/weeks)

scala> Json.parse("""{ "weeks": [1] }""").validate[A]
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[A] = JsError(List((/weeks,List(ValidationError(List(error.minLength),WrappedArray(2))))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. Ended up using this, as I wanted to have fixed length (not just minimun):
`.filterNot(ValidationError(s"Length of the list must be $length"))(_.length != length)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, will edit the post soon. I mixed up your requirements after looking at default Play minLength readers :)

Comment: Small update on play 2.4.x:
 ```.filterNot(JsError(s"Length of the list must be $length"))(_.length != length)``` 
as the ```.filterNot(ValidationError)``` is depriciated